# Issue with sound system, no sound, empty output/input

Tags: updates, system, sound

So i am super happy with how things work on ElementaryOS 6.1, but unfortunately i have no sound, already tried all google/reddit fixes but nothings helped.

In settings/sound both fields output and input (microphone) are empty.

Please help:)
Thanks in advance

PS: im using Huawei matebook15

Comment: There seems to be a general lack of support in linux kernels for your device, as described here: https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/3248 (basically the audio chip is too new) You maybe want to try the latest kernel if you are willing to experiment ?

Comment: obviously i would like to make some tests, i like ElOS so hoping to move 100% of my work to it:)

Comment: You can try updating the kernel. Follow the steps here: https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu#:~:text=cd%20/tmp-,Download%20kernel,-Latest%20mainline%20from   This might result in a non-functional system, so make sure you have nothing of value stored on it in case of a reinstall. Even if the kernel update succedes, the audio issue might still be  present, so this is not a solution, more like an experiment. If it fails miserably, you might have to reinstall, so proceed only if you have nothing to lose.

Comment: Well system crash at the start with error "First you must install kernel" - something like that...